# How do you fill the area above a curve of points with one color and below the same curve with a different color in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

In MATLAB, I have the following sets of points:

```
T_arr =
        1000
         500
         400
         300
         200
         100

results =

    2.6000    
    2.2000    
    2.1500    
    2.1000    
    2.0000    
    1.8000
```

When I plot them it looks like this:

```
plot(T_arr, results); hold on; 
plot(T_arr, results,'*'); 
xlabel('T'); 
ylabel('result'); 
title('T vs. result')
```

[image]

I would like to color the region above the curve in one color (say red) and the region below the curve in a different color (say blue). How can this be done in MATLAB?

I am aware there are two functions in MATLAB called [fill](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) and [area](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html) , but I am unclear how to use them for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `fill` we need to provide set of points that forms closed shape.
We will use points from your data set and top left (x0,y0) and bottom right (x1, y1) corners of the picture.

[image]

Now we need to find these coords and call fill for two sets of points with different colors (last parameter in `fill`). You can avoid using `max` and `min` if data is sorted or limits are known. I plot areas before the line to make sure that markers will be visible - that is also the reason why I didn't used red and blue colors.

```
T_arr = [1000, 500, 400,300, 200, 100];
results =[2.6000,    2.2000,   2.1500,    2.1000,    2.0000, 1.8000 ];
plot(T_arr, results); hold on; 
x0 = min(T_arr);
y0 = max(results);
x1 = max(T_arr);
y1 = min(results);
fill([x0, T_arr],[y0, results],'g');
fill([x1, T_arr],[y1, results],'y');
plot(T_arr, results,'*'); 
xlabel('T'); 
ylabel('result'); 
title('T vs. result');
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: perfect. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.